# Why linux has enough memory but swap is used

Tags: linux, memory, erlang

I have a server run an erlang application, something like riak..

Before the problem, the memory usage like this

[image: memory before]

but after a long time, the cached is clear and system begin use swap.
[image: memory later]

now I have two question..

1. Why the system release the cached? This cause the problem that the system's IO is higher than before
2. Why the system still has enough memory, but swap is still used..

Below is the top information:
[image: top]

**Update**: this problem come again..
[image]
Since I have run command

`sudo swapoff -a`

so the system don't use swap, the system runs well.
Now the problem is why system release page cached..?
And what the situation is that the system will release pgae cache?

**Update**: I have fixed this problem..
I got answer from the book Understanding Linux Kernel
The book say that if there is enough free memory, the page is kept in the cache for an indefinite period of time and can then be reused by other processes without accessing the disk.

I think this means that the system will release the cache if the page cache has stay in the system for a long time.

After I read the linux source, I will update it. Why the system will release page cached even it has enough memory?

Thanks

**update**

1. the reason why linux swap the memory to swap area even the system have enough memory?

if we swap the memory when a process find there is not enough memory, then it will need a long time for the process to get enough memory. It will need to call page frame reclaim.

2. the reason why we set vm.swappiness=0, there will still have swap.

There is a global_reclaim in the backend. which don't check the swappiness value

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Will make the system swap only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to your processes running (ex: mysql, java etc...)

If you set a memory limit too low for theses processes and sometimes they need more, the memory missing is not taken onto the buffers but on swap.

I think this could explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

i.e. debian is swapping really seldom used data. I think this behavior is considered as an optimization. 
This question directly corresponds to this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/why-use-swap-when-there-is-more-than-enough-free-space-in-ram/2664#2664). 
You can set the swappiness factor:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a problem (swap)

when the linux OS is running it "put aside" some of its running services in the swap partition.

but if you'll start using those services they will brought back into RAM.

Comment: Yes, what you said about swap partition is right,  But the problem here is that why linux release page cached even it has enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that reading from the swap is slightly faster than reading from the disk.

Assuming it, keeping things in the swap is a good thing (doesn't mean that your memory is full).

So, lets say you have 4 Gb of memory, and you have 2 Gb of free memory. Then you load an application A, which is 2Gb, you are going to have all your 4Gb of memory fully occupied. Then you close application X and load application Y (1Gb). It means that half of application X will be moved to swap and the main memory will now contain Y and the some 'cache' for half-of X.

In this case, you will have the following scenario:

- 4 Gb full memory
- 2 Gb occupied by the system
- 1 Gb for application Y
- 1 Gb of cache for X

Swap
 * 1 Gb for X (that were removed to load application Y)

Comment: thanks for you reply.  Here I think we can't compare reading from swap and reading from disk. Since the data we store in swap is anonymous pages, the anonymous pages is used for user mode process stack, or heap. And the page cache is stored in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the "swappiness" level to increase or diminish the kernel's reliance on swap space.